# How to split an .mgf file

Tags: r

I have an .mgf file I need to split up as the file is too large to be read in with my computer.
The function to read in the .mgf file must be readMgfData() and it must be done using R.
I have tried to group my .mgf file with chunk=file[] with no luck.

Also, I tried RStudio cloud but I couldn’t install MsnBase for some reason.

If you know how to deal with this issue I would be VERY thankful for your guidance.